# Setting weekend background color

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, calendar

I'm making a calendar in LaTeX with tikz-pgf and I would like to set  to gray the background color for the weekend. In the examples I found on the Internet and in the documentation, I can see how to setup the foreground color:

```
if (weekend) [red]
```

but something like this does not work

```
if (weekend) [fill=gray]
```

This is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \calendar(mycal) [dates=2013-09-01 to 2013-09-last, 
        week list, 
        month label above centered,
        month text=\%mt \%y0    
        ]
        if (Sunday) [red]
    if (weekend) [fill=gray];

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I can't find it in the documentation but `if (weekend) [nodes={fill=gray}]` fills the nodes.

Comment: @MarkWibrow This is pretty much the same as `if (weekend) [every day/.append style={fill=gray}]` as the `nodes` key just appends its argument to the `every node` style.

Comment: Thanks, this works almost as I need. There is a way to expand the background's width a little bit, so that e.g. both "8" and "23" background's width are the same?

Comment: @FloDD Have you seen my comment on MarcoDaniel’s answer? You might need to reduce the `text width` a little bit, because the nodes overlap slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@everyone Solved in this way:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \calendar [dates=2013-09-01 to 2013-09-last,
        week list,
        month label above centered,
        month text=\%mt \%y0
    ]
    if (Sunday) [red]
    if (weekend) [nodes={fill=black!20,minimum size=1.7em}];
\end{tikzpicture}
```